# Same Bosch batteries, but one battery only works in one tool, what can I do?

Tags: repair, tools, troubleshooting, battery

So, I have some BAT612 18V batteries from Bosch.

I should be able to use both batteries with either of my tools (Angle Grinder - GWS18V-45PC, Drill - DDS181A), but one battery works in both tools and the other only works in the drill.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Or maybe how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe one is tired and the circuitry in the grinder doesn't consider it adequate. The tools are designed to not over-drain LI batteries because that can destroy them.

Comment: @isherwood OCP/UVP is handled by the battery's charge controller (built into each battery pack), not the tool.

Comment: You're probably right, but I wonder if it isn't a little of both. My only other idea is a quirky contact issue.

Comment: Yeah, I could see that the contact issue, but they both are fairly straight and new, but I did notice when I clicked the battery in that doesn't work in the Angle Grinder. I can push the battery check button and everything is OK until i press the tools trigger. Then it cuts off.

Answer (score -1):

Contact issue, I think. Please see if one tool has a deeper contact than the other. Or rough up the tool contact with some sand paper.